# Groupby, filter rows between specific strings in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I would like to group `df` by `test`, then filter out rows which are in between the rows where column `A` is `STATION` and column `A` is `END`(I've marked them in the `df` below).

Note that the letters are case-sensitive(i.e., has to be `STATION` and not `Station`).

`df` looks like this:

```
     A        B        C       test
0    NaN      NaN    NaN       NaN
1    TEXT     <1     >1        555
2    EXAMPLE  NaN    NaN       NaN
3    tj       XYZ    NaN       NaN
4    NaN      xyz    NaN       NaN
5    Station  NaN    NaN       NaN
6    NaN      NaN    NaN       NaN
7    STATION  NaN    NaN       NaN          * Filter Start 
8    Code1   <1000   >1000     555
9    Code2   <1000   >1000     555
10   END      NaN    NaN       NaN          * Filter End
11   TEXT     NaN    NaN       NaN
0    NaN      NaN    NaN       NaN
1    Station  NaN    NaN       NaN
2    NaN      NaN    NaN       NaN
3    STATION  NaN    NaN       NaN          * Filter Start 
4    Code3   <1000   >1000     666
5    END      NaN    NaN       NaN          * Filter End
     ...
```

Expected output:

```
8    Code1   <1000   >1000     555
9    Code2   <1000   >1000     555
4    Code3   <1000   >1000     666
```

Comment: Are there always same `non-nan` values in the `test` column between each set of `STATION` and `END`?

Comment: Hi @ShubhamSharma, not necessarily, the values could be different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I didn't really get what you meant by "grouping by `test`". The output doesn't really seem grouped. Nevertheless, I got the filtering down. Here it is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=cols)
df['ind'] = 0
df.loc[df['A'] == 'STATION', 'ind'] = 1
df.loc[df['A'] == 'END', 'ind'] = -1
df['ind'] = df['ind'].cumsum()
df[(df['ind']==1) & (df['A'] != 'STATION')]
```